# Get URL parameter function that gets value of url part or returns true if it's there but with no value?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using the following function to get a URL parameter.

```
function gup(name, url) {
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\\]');
  var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]'+name+'=?([^&#]*)').exec(url || window.location.href);
  return results == null ? null : results[1];
}
```

It works only if the parameter has a value, for example.

```
gup('a', 'http://example.com/page.php?a=1&b=2');
```

will return 1. But if I try

```
gup('a', 'http://example.com/page.php?a&b=2');
```

It returns null. I want it to return true because parameter "a" exists in that url, even though it has no value it's still there and gup() should return true. Could I get a bit of help rewriting this? I'm not that good with regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your second example, it actually doesn't return `null`, it returns an empty string.

Empty strings are *falsy*, they coerce to `false` in boolean context, so you could use this in the second branch of the ternary.

There you know that something was matched (in `results[1]`), and you can return `true` only if the match is *falsy* (an empty string):

```
function gup(name, url) {
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\\]');
  var results = new RegExp('[?&]'+name+'=?([^&#]*)').exec(url || window.location.href);
  return results == null ? null : results[1] || true;
}

gup('a', 'http://example.com/page.php?a&b=2');   // true
gup('a', 'http://example.com/page.php?a=1&b=2'); // "1"
gup('a', 'http://example.com/page.php?b=2');     // null
```

Comment: Thank you. Didn't realize it was so simple.

Answer (score -1):

When the page loads, with PHP or any server-side language of your choice output a hidden input foreach GET parameter.

```
foreach($_GET as $Name => $Value) {
     echo '<input type="hidden" id="'.$Name.'" value="'.$Value.'">';
}
```

Then, with javascript you can get the value of that hidden input which will give you the value of the url parameter.

```
var parameterValue = document.getElementById('parameter').value;
```